# How to retrieve data when I have following type of data in a database?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I am learning MySQL(Beginner). And I am trying to solve one question in which I got stuck.
[image: Database]

From the above database ORDER_TABLE, I am trying to extract out the ORDER_ID when user inputs the various fruits, stationary items and drinks.  Name of respective items (Apple, Book, Tea) will be provided us. We need to check whether the database contains the items provided by the user and if exists we need to return ORDER_ID of it, if not a message saying "No such order yet".

How to check and extract it? Do we need to use loop here? If yes, let us suppose, there is quantity of items provided to us. But how to use loop here? I am totally confused. Beginners tutorials does not teach this kind of question and its solution.

Or, can we break this data in several tables and then get the ORDER_ID??

Comment: I'll just recommend you the better schema structure, where you will have orderItem (apple, Book, Tea etc) and have orderItemType which will be Fruit, Stationary, Drink etc. This way you don't have to change ORDER_TABLE whenever you want to add new category, as well you might have orderItemType as a table to hold all types. 

This new structure will really make every query much easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach uses aggregation.  For example, to find all orders which have `(Apple, Book, Tea)`, we can try:

```
SELECT Order_ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Order_ID
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Fruits = 'Apple' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Stationary = 'Book' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Drinks = 'Teat' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: It gave me solution for now. But, if I have to check all the items, I need to use loop, right? For example there are a lot of fruits items. Using this process I need to check all the fruits. So, I will have to check all those items repeating these lines for each fruit. It will be a cumbersome. So, how to use loop here, with assumption that, quantity of items (fruits) is given. Let's say 20 fruits.

Comment: I don't understand your follow up question.  If you have a handful of different business questions, then it is considered reasonable to use a handful of different queries.